# Lower state of energy for 'connected' molecules

Tags: energy, surface-tension

Quote from Wikipedia:

> Another way to view surface tension is in terms of energy. A molecule in contact with a neighbor is in a **lower state of energy** than if it were alone (not in contact with a neighbor).

As I understand the above statement, is that if two molecules (of the same liquid) are separated, then they have a larger energy as when they are together. Can you please explain a bit why this happens? Is there a physical/chemical reason? Thank you.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20598/causes-of-surface-tension-between-two-fluids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably referring to the intermolecular forces operating between individual molecules of the same liquid. In the case of water, this could be hydrogen-bonding or general dispersion forces. These forces typically act as 'stabilising' forces which can be viewed as a lower energy state.

When the molecules are separated, these close-range forces can no longer operate, so the molecules are considered to be at a higher energy state. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_forces) article is quite helpful on the subject.